# Getting lowest non-zero value from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the largest and smallest value / values from a dictionary.

Where the lowest value should not be zero, but the closest to it.
If there is a 0 present and the values are `K:0 K:3 K:7 K:1` it should return 1 and not 0.

I've tried using the min / max functions, but haven't been able to get them to work properly. Want to get all values even when there are multiple.

Example Dictionary.

```
Dict = {"D1" : "0", "D2" : "2", "D3" : "7", "D4" : "7", "D5" : "4"}
Highest = max(Dict, key=Dict.get)
Lowest = min(Dict, key=Dict.get)
```

Only gets me D3 and D1 respectively. Also returns the 0.
Highest works in most cases, but Lowest returns the 0. Should there be a check after lowest has been assigned and iterate over the dictionary again?
Highest and Lowest can be a list or a single Value doesn't really matter.

My current code looks something like this.

```
Dict = {"D1" : "0", "D2" : "2", "D3" : "7", "D4" : "7", "D5" : "4"}
Highest = max(Dict, key=Dict.get)
Lowest = min(Dict, key=Dict.get)
for key, value in Dict.items():
    if value == Dict[Highest]:
        Do x
    elif value == Dict[Lowest]:
        Do y
    else:
        Do z
```

Which mostly works, except for the above mentioned 0 getting returned.

## Edit

Was doing some more testing and the dictionaries received had a chance to be full of zero values or the same positive integer.
Which made the solution a bit wonky.
Decided to change it up a bit and iterate over the items instead by assigning a start value for both highest and lowest.
When iterating through the dictionary I assigned new values to highest and lowest if they were either > or < respectively.
Something like the code below. (Tried to comment with some code, but the formatting got messed up, so decided to edit the question a bit instead).

```
Highest = -1
Lowest = 1000000 # Highest Value the dictionary values may have
for key in dict:
    if dict[key] > Highest and dict[key] != 0:
        Highest = dict[key]
    if dict[key] < Lowest and dict[key] != 0:
    Lowest = dict[key]

# Then possible to iterate over the dictionary and get the highest and lowest values from the dictionary.
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value == Highest and Highest != -1:
        Do X
    elif value != 0:
        if value == Lowest and Lowest != 1000000:
            Do Y
        else:
            Do z
    else:
        Do z
```

Comment: Do you actually want the *keys* with min/max value, or the min/max *value*?

Comment: Want the keys from the highest and lowest value in the dictionary which are not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter first, *then* `min`/`max` the filtered data. Sticking to your design as closely as possible:

```
nozeroes = {k: v for k, v in Dict.items() if v > 0}  # New dict with only positive values

# Only change to original version is replacing Dict with nozeroes
Highest = max(nozeroes, key=Dict.get)
Lowest = min(nozeroes, key=Dict.get)
```

Note: If you just want the values themselves, and don't care about the keys, this is even easier:

```
nonzero_values = [v for v in Dict.values() if v > 0]
Highest = max(nonzero_values)
Lowest = min(nonzero_values)
```

Comment: Implementation worked great, but got problems with the dictionary having the possibility to being full zeros or 1's.
Decided to loop over the areas instead and do something like this.

`Highest = -1
Lowest = 1000000
    for key in dict:
        if dict[key] > Highest and dict[key] != 0:
            Highest = dict[key]
        if dict[key] < Lowest and dict[key] != 0:
            Lowest = dict[key]`
Then testing iterating over the dict and checking if the value is not either -1 or 1000000
Was my bad with the question (Am new on the platform) :)
Was not clear enough and vague.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from math import inf

Dict = {"D1": "0", "D2": "2", "D3": "7", "D4": "7", "D5": "4"}
Highest = max(Dict, key=lambda x: Dict[x] or inf)
Lowest = min(Dict, key=lambda x: Dict[x] or inf)
```

Comment: Given that `0` is the only falsy numeric value, the `lambda` could simplify to: `lambda x: Dict[x] or inf`; there's no need for `.get` (we know the key exists), and when `Dict[x]` evaluates to `0` (which is falsy) the `or` continues and the expression evaluates to `inf`, when it's non-zero, the `or` short-circuits, producing the non-zero value.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is more elegant. I was just in a hurry.